SVG image xlinked in a parent SVG doesn't show up in HTML page
I opened a PDF of a page in Inkscape 1.4 (e7c3feb100, 2024-10-09) and saved as SVG. The page already had a piece of SVG clip art in it, so in the page's SVG I replaced that with a <image xlink:href> to the original clip art SVG in its own layer. The parent SVG and its linked SVG render fine in Firefox and chromium-browser, see https://skierpage.com/bugs/linked_scrollbar_not_shown.svg . But when I put the parent SVG in an HTML page, I don't see the linked SVG in either browser, see https://skierpage.com/bugs/linked_scrollbar_not_shown.html .
This sounds like SO question SVG not showing up with use xlink, only with img src , but I couldn't reproduce that problem in these recent browsers. Per a response to that question I added "a fragment identifier that references that id" [on the linked SVG's top-level <svg> element], and it didn't help.
